# Wlst how to assign output of listAppStripes() to grantAppRole()

Tags: python, dynamic, input, output, wlst

I'm new to Python and WLST.  I'm trying to write a Python script that retrieves the the Application Stripes for a deployed application and assigned it to appStripes values in the grantAppRole.

For example:

1. Connect to Admin Server
2. Deploy the new application
3. Determine the new application stripes for the deployed application
   listAppStripes()

Example:

```
wls:/myapp_domain/serverRuntime> listAppStripes()

MyApp#V14.1.0.0.17-b585_APP_75.111.73
wls:/myapp_domain/serverRuntime>
```

4. GrantAppRole permission. I need to be able to pass the Application Stripe output from Step #3 to this next command:

   ```
   grantAppRole(appStripe="MyApp#V14.1.0.0.17-b585_APP_75.111.73",appRoleName="ROLE_USER",principalClass="weblogic.security.principal.WLSGroupImpl",principalName="LDAP_ROLE_PROD",forceValidate="false")
   ```

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the value in a variable and then using that variable in the `grantAppRole()` function call -

```
app_stripes = listAppStripes()
```

I think this might be returning an array , so try using `app_stripes[0]` , to get the first element. You can test it out, what is the exact value returned and use that accordingly.

```
grantAppRole(appStripe=app_stripes[0],appRoleName="ROLE_USER",principalClass="weblogic.security.principal.WLSGroupImpl",principalName="LDAP_ROLE_PROD",forceValidate="false")
```

---

Seems like `listAppStripes()` is just printing the values and not returning the value.

You can do one thing, which is to redirect the `stdout` to a string buffer just before running the`listAppStripes()` , and then correctly redirect it back. and then get your value from the string buffer. Example -

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import sys
oldstdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = mystdout = StringIO()
listAppStripes()
sys.stdout = oldstdout
app_stripes=mystdout.getvalue()
app_stripes = app_stripes.replace('wls:/myapp_domain/domainRuntime> ','').strip().split()
```

After this, `app_stripes` would be a list of all the stripes , and you can use the method given in the start to call `grantAppRole()` .

Comment: I'm having an issue trying to store the value in a variable:  

wls:/myapp_domain/domainRuntime> app_stripes=listAppStripes()
Already in Domain Runtime Tree

MyApp#V14.1.0.0.17-b585_APP_75.111.73
wls:/myapp_domain/domainRuntime> print app_stripes
None

Comment: Yea, seems like it only prints, does not return anything, please check my latest update.